# a thread related issue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am learning to use thread. And I find that I can use the following

```
mutex mx;

void func(int id)
{
    mx.lock();
    cout << "hey , thread:"<<id << "!" << endl;
    mx.unlock();
}
int main(){
    vector<thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        threads.emplace_back(thread(func , i));
    for(thread & t : threads)
        t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

while I can't do in main()

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++)
{
    thread t(func , i);
    threads.emplace_back(t);
}
```

Can any one explain this a little?

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: When using `emplace_back`, the element is constructed in place. All you'll want to pass are the constructor's arguments, not create an unnecessary object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the object:

```
thread t(func, i);
threads.push_back(std::move(t));
```

`emplace` also works, but `push_back` is idiomatic in this case. And of course `#include <utility>`.

Comment: I tried this and it works. Thanks . I see the document  that " copy [deleted] (3) thread (const thread&) = delete; " from reference of thread